# c# label not show correct content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with label.content...

the content is "my_text_formated" but he show "mytext_formated"

why it make this? :/

(I programming in C# wpf, and I use VisualStudio 15 professional)

Code for reproduce (For try, you just need to click on the button);

**XAML**

```
        <Button x:Name="btnFormat" Content="formatText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnFormat_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblResult" Content="defaultResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="50,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="my text formated" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
private void btnFormat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Content = toFormatString(txtBoxText.Text);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER_SET_CONTENT =>" + lblResult.Content);
    }

    public string toFormatString(string text)
    {
        List<String> FormatList = text.Split(' ').ToList();
        String result = "";
        foreach (String s in FormatList)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                result += "_";
            result += s;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("IN_FORMAT_METHOD =>" + result);
        return result;
    }
```

**Output result :**

Console :

IN_FORMAT_METHOD =>my_text_formated

AFTER_SET_CONTENT =>my_text_formated

Windows :
mytext_formated

Comment: Use a TextBlock to display text.

Comment: Ty, I have not find this help when I have searched .. sorry ^^'
When, how we put the resolve tag on the question?